# Why this code's JTextArea occupies entire JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, textarea, frame, layout-manager

I expect part of my frame contains the JTextArea but it occupies entirely. I cannot trace the error here.

```
import java.awt.*;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class EchoServer 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       CalcFrame c = new CalcFrame();
       CalcTextArea a = new CalcTextArea();
   } 
}

class CalcTextArea 
{
    JTextArea historyDisplayer  = new JTextArea("",50,20);
    CalcTextArea()
    {  
          //historyDisplayer.setVisible(true);
          historyDisplayer.insert("Hello World", 0);              
          Color bg = new Color(23,34,56);              
          historyDisplayer.setBackground(bg);               
          historyDisplayer.setBackground(bg);
    }       
}

class CalcFrame extends CalcTextArea
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    CalcFrame()
    {
        frame.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("CALCULATOR");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(historyDisplayer);

    }
    private static int  DEFAULT_WIDTH = 299,DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 190; 
}
```

Comment: Try `frame.setLayout(null);frame.add(historyDisplayer);` but actually you should be using a layout manager.

Comment: @BalaR hey .. why do you suggest null layout? You know it's a sin which will cause much pain without any pleasure ;-)

Comment: +1 for posting http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JFrame` by default uses `BorderLayout`. When you just add something onto a `BorderLayout` component like `JFrame`, it would add to the very center of the `BorderLayout` (if you did not specify where to add the component), and it takes up the entire `JFrame`.

You should use the correct [layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to adjust them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Absolute layout. It's on the Layouts Pallet.

Or enable it with :

```
frame = new JFrame();
... //your code here

// to set absolute layout.
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

This way, you can freely place the control anywhere you like.